# Additional settings after installation of Apache Tomcat in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: tomcat, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VM which runs `Ubuntu 16.04` and `LAMP` and currently is hosting some WordPress sites.

I have implemented locally a web project which runs in `Tomcat` server and I want to deploy it in the VM. I am planning to install [Apache Tomcat 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and then deploy the war file of my project there.

My question is :

1. After the installation of the `Tomcat 8` in the VM, should I make an extra setting? in the Apache WebServer or somewhere else?
2. To connect my webApplication with a domain name, when setting the Virtual host in the `.conf` file, in the `DocumentRoot` I will add the path of the webapp?

**.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/webapps/webApplication
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, either serve requests to the application using the `mod_jk` connector, or by configuring apache as a reverse proxy with `mod_proxy` and sending requests to the tomcat web server. Both will work as a subdomain or as a Directory or Alias directive, so set up will be along these lines:

This is a simple configuration for mod_jk (from https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)

```
 # Load mod_jk module
    LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
    # Add the module (activate this lne for Apache 1.3)
    # AddModule     mod_jk.c
    # Where to find workers.properties
    JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
    # Where to put jk shared memory
    JkShmFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
    # Where to put jk logs
    JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
    # Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
    JkLogLevel    info
    # Send requests for context /examples to worker named worker1
    JkMount  /examples/* worker1
```

and this is a simple setup for a reverse proxy which can be added to a `VirtualHost` or a `Directory` (official documentation:https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/proxy.html)

```
 ProxyRequests off 
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/ 
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
```